# Flutter - How to get linear gradient across all edges?

Tags: flutter, containers, gradient, linear-gradients

[image]

```
LinearGradient(
                    //tileMode: TileMode.clamp,
                    colors: [
                      kRecordButtonColor.withOpacity(0.4),
                      kRecordButtonColor,
                      kRecordButtonColor,
                      kRecordButtonColor.withOpacity(0.4),
                    ],
                    stops: const [
                      0,
                      0.2,
                      0.8,
                      1,
                    ],
                  ),
```

As you can see this code only helps me get gradients across 2 edges, I need it along all 4 edges.

Comment: Maybe you can use RadialGradient?

Comment: Tried, doesn't give the desired result. It's not a simple container. Since its wrapped with Inkwell, it's a bit more complex I guess.

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead of your Container:

```
Stack(
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          children: [
            Container(
              margin: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
              width: 55,
              height: 55,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.red,
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                  gradient: LinearGradient(
                    colors: [
                      Colors.red.withOpacity(0.5),
                      Colors.red,
                      Colors.red,
                      Colors.red.withOpacity(0.5),
                    ],
                    stops: const [
                      0,
                      0.2,
                      0.8,
                      1,
                    ],
                  )),
            ),
            Container(
              margin: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
              width: 55,
              height: 55,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.red,
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                  gradient: LinearGradient(
                    begin: Alignment.topCenter,
                    end: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                    colors: [
                      Colors.white.withOpacity(0.5),
                      Colors.white.withOpacity(0.0),
                      Colors.white.withOpacity(0.0),
                      Colors.white.withOpacity(0.5),
                    ],
                    stops: const [
                      0,
                      0.2,
                      0.8,
                      1,
                    ],
                  )),
            ),
          ],
        ),
```

Comment: I appreciate the effort but this is a really ugly hack. I tried this for some time adjusting a few values but this still doesn't cover the corners. Basically when you increase the corner radius, the corners look darker than  the edge.